# Travis CI api requests overrides the keys

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a default config set in .travis.yml for one of my git repos. I want to trigger this repo build through the Travis CI api. I'm able to do this successfully. But when I want to add additional parameters like environment variables in the api, it is simply overriding the environment variables in this dependent build.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds

Could some one please help how I can add environment variables in the api without having to override the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

I got the confirmation from Travis CI team that keys will always be overridden. Below is the message.

*Unfortunately I think that this is a limitation of the API at the moment, but I will open an internal issue to investigate it further. One way to help with this would be to move global environment variables to the repository settings, please see https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings for more details.*

*